Pybind11 does not hold GIL when run python code
I have an cpp file write with pybind11 extension and then I compile it and import to python as module example
My purpose is to test if I can run cpp concurrently with python without any lock.
Normally, because of GIL when you run multithread python that access the same object, you do not need a lock
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/functional.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <Python.h>
namespace py = pybind11;
std::mutex mtx;


void call_python_object(py::object obj, float arg1, float arg2) {
    obj.attr("my_python_function")(arg1,arg2);
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
     m.def("call_python_object", &call_python_object, "Call a Python object");
}

The python file is as follow
import pybind11
import example
import threading
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,value=0):
        self.value = value
    def my_python_function(self, arg1: float, arg2: float) -> float:
        self.value+=arg1
        self.value+=arg2
        return float(self.value)
        
myclass = MyClass()
def cpp_thread():
    for i in range(50000):
        example.call_python_object(myclass,1.0,1.0)
def python_thead():
    for i in range(50000):
        myclass.my_python_function(1,1)
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=cpp_thread)
thread1.start()
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=python_thead)
thread2.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
print(myclass.value)

Normally, the result should be 200000 but it is not.
Why there is an race condition, does that mean pybind11 does not hold the GIL when execute python code

"My purpose is to test if I can run cpp concurrently with python without any lock" - you can't test that, really. If it works in your test due to coincidence, you incorrectly think the lock is unnecessary. A next run might not be so lucky. The common observation is that tests can only show the presence of bugs, not their absence. "Race conditions due to missing locks" is a subclass of bugs, and that observation applies in full to them,

Have you read https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/misc.html#global-interpreter-lock-gil ? It directly contradicts the assumption in the title.

self.value+=arg1 is not threadsafe. you should fix that first.
